# How fast is rsync?

Tags: performance, rsync, data-transfer, file-transfer

Anyone ever transferred large files with it?

What is the main advantage over ftp and other methods?

Speed? or slicing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it keeps 2 directories in sync. so it's mainly useful if you need to do that since it'll only transfer the ones on the sender that aren't on the receiver, or let you delete ones on one that aren't on the other, etc.

for just copying large files, use scp/ftp/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Speed, it does [very effective compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Algorithm). Range of features, it can be tailored significantly.